# Are there still systems around with a /bin/sh binary?

Tags: shell, distributions

`/bin/sh`, the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) created in 1977, used to be the default shell for Unix systems.

Nowadays this file still exists but mostly just as a symbolic link to the default POSIX-compatible shell installed on the system:

- on RHEL/CentOS it points to `/bin/bash`, the Bourne Again shell
- on Ubuntu Linux it points to `/bin/dash`, the Debian Almquist shell
- on Debian it points to `/bin/dash` (6.0 and later; older Debian releases had it point to `/bin/bash`)

Which made me curious: Is there a Unix system, or Linux distro, that still provides a **binary** for `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/38906

Comment: See also: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shells/

Comment: macOS does. Maybe that counts as FreeBSD.

Comment: [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) for embedded linux systems with small memory footprint often will use just a plain /bin/sh (symlink into busybox). Not sure if you want this to count as system with a /bin/sh binary.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98892/why-does-no-one-use-the-true-bourne-shell-as-bin-sh

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## `/bin/sh` is not always a symlink

NetBSD is one system where `/bin/sh` is not a symlink.  The default install includes three shells: the Korn shell, the C shell, and a modified Almquist shell.  Of these, the latter is installed only as `/bin/sh`.

Interix (the second POSIX subsystem for Windows NT) does not have `/bin/sh` as a symlink.  A single binary of the MirBSD Korn shell is linked twice as `/bin/sh` and `/bin/mksh`.

FreeBSD and its derivative TrueOS (formerly PC-BSD) have the TENEX C shell as both `/bin/csh` and `/bin/tcsh`, and the Almquist shell as (only) `/bin/sh`.  No symlink there, either.

OpenBSD has the (original) C shell as `/bin/csh` and the PD Korn shell linked thrice as `/bin/sh`, `/bin/ksh`, and `/bin/rksh`.  Also no symlink.

Comment: There's stuff to say about OpenSolaris and Schillix too.

Comment: I would have been quite content for you to have had the points.  No worries.  @schily is an occasional Stack Exchange contributor.  Maybe xe will fill in Schillix and OpenSolaris.

Comment: I fail to understand why a symlink is that important. If in the `/bin` directory I do `ln ksh sh`, there is a `hardlink` called `sh`, it is not a symlink. Is it a `sh` binary?

Comment: I believe that what is intended with some binary placed or symlinked in '/bin/sh' is what matters. All systems AFAIK have a `/bin/sh`. None AFAIK ships with an old ATT sh. As an example, dash in debian systems is intended to be as close as *is possible* to an old `/bin/sh`.

Comment: You are taking issue with the premise _of the question_.  Such commentary is mis-placed against an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Solaris 10 still has the legacy Bourne shell binary as `/bin/sh`, and this is definitely **not** a POSIX compatible shell.

Hopefully, Solaris 11 broke this annoying tradition by providing `ksh93` as `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 4):

This OSX box has /bin/sh as:

```
$ ls -alF /bin/sh
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  632672 May  5  2016 /bin/sh*
$ uname -a
Darwin AUS-LM-000421.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Vers...
```

Comment: Interestingly, both those files report being GNU bash 3.2.57(1)-release on my laptop, but differ by a few kilobytes (632672 bytes for /bin/sh vs 628496 bytes for /bin/bash).

Comment: From the man page of [`sh`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/sh.1.html) on macOS: »sh is a POSIX-compliant command interpreter (shell). It is implemented by re-execing as either bash(1), dash(1), or zsh(1) as determined by the symbolic link located at /private/var/select/sh.« On my system `/private/var/select/sh` points to `/bin/bash`.