# Sharing environment variables between zsh and bourne shell (for crontab)

Tags: zsh, cron, environment-variables, bourne-shell

I set JAVA_HOME in .zshrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

which is fine for interactive programs. But I have JVM programs running via cron, which uses Bourne shell. The bourne shell programs keep giving me this:

```
groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
```

What's the neatest way to solve this? I don't remember having to worry about this before. Currently I'm setting JAVA_HOME on every crontab entry which is burdensome and redundant.

Comment: You know you can set environment variables in the crontab on lines saying just `VARIABLE=value`, right? You don't have to set the variable for each and every crontab entry.

Comment: ...unless you have multiple crontab entries running JVM programs ;) Hello microservices.

Comment: What do you mean by "crontab entry"? Do you mean separate crotabs, or separate schedules in a single crontab? You only need to set `JAVA_HOME` once in a crontab file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to your own user's crontab, to avoid duplicating the definition of `JAVA_HOME` you can `export` the variable in `~/.zshenv` (instead of `~/.zshrc`), which is read even in non-interactive, non-login shells, and run `zsh -c 'sh /path/to/script'` in your cron job (replacing `sh`, based on what the program called "Bourne shell" in your question actually is, if appropriate).

Alternatively, if you are fine with defining `JAVA_HOME` in multiple places and if your `sh` implementation supports this<sup>1</sup>, you may `export` it in `~/.profile` and invoke `sh` as a login shell by either appending `-l` to the script's shebang or changing the cron job's command into `sh -l /path/to/script`.

Though, in the end, the most convenient solution is probably to simply add

```bsh
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

as a line at the top of your crontab (unless you have distinct cron jobs that need distinct values of `JAVA_HOME`, of course).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Your `sh`, which is [unlikely to be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98892/315749) a "true" Bourne shell, may have a `-l` option if it is actually a link to (for instance) `bash` or `dash`. As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) pointed out in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640770/sharing-environment-variables-between-zsh-and-bourne-shell-for-crontab/640777?noredirect=1#comment1201873_640777), 1) it does not have it if it is the Bourne shell or an implementation of [POSIX `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sh.html) (e.g., `sh` has no `-l` option on {Free,Net,Open}BSD); and 2) not all the implementations that support `-l` will read `~/.profile` when given that option.</sub>

Comment: Hmmm, if I have to make a modification like this to crontab, I might as well just create a file called `~/.zshrc-java` since I have a lot of dotfiles, organized by functionality (`~/.zshrc-git`, `~/.zshrc-p4`, `~/.zshrc-work`, `~/.zshrc-home`).

Comment: ... or add `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/` at the top of your crontab, instead of setting it for each job. The point of this answer is to avoid duplicating the definition of a variable (since you asked about "sharing") and, given that there is no profile/initialization file that both `sh` and `zsh` read by default, a clean way to do that is by letting `zsh` define the environment for the cron job.

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that. That's the simplest solution, though I need to use that sparingly. Self-contained single lines are easier to debug.

Comment: I'll mark this answer correct though I'll just add an extra line to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Actually the `~/.profile` approach seems to be the "real" solution (maybe that should be marked `3.`). I just need to make sure I copy it each time I reinstall Ubuntu and not wonder why my restored cronjobs aren't working..

Comment: I removed the numbered list to make clear that the three paragraphs correspond to three distinct solutions. I'd guess the "best" approach is ultimately a matter of taste.

Comment: Note that neither the Bourne shell nor the POSIX specification of `sh` support a `-l` option. A few modern implementations of POSIX `sh` do though. Not all will read `.profile` with that option though.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in both systemwide configfiles respectively `/etc/bash.bashrc` (`/etc/bashrc` on non-Debian systems) and `/etc/zsh/zshenv` (`/etc/zshenv`

As the syntax is the same, you can just copy-paste

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

that in both files

Comment: Will Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`) read ~/.bashrc?

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/` is not valid syntax in the Bourne shell, but I doubt @SridharSarnobat's `sh` is a Bourne shell. I don't think any currently maintained OS still use that shell now that Solaris 10 is end-of-life.

Comment: In any case, bashrc is for the bash shell, not sh (Bourne or not), and only read by bash for interactive shells (and in some builds of bash and under some conditions when invoked over ssh/rsh), and not when running as `sh`.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Good to know. I should probably stop using Bourne shell for scripts too then