# Why do certain programs or systems rely on symlinks?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, macos

### Context

As I was navigating through the file-system to find the persisted files from a mounted docker volume, I found it difficult to unravel the unending `ls/cd/tree` of directories only to find more symlinks... *Maybe this is the wrong question to ask since my search is not producing a satisfying answer*

### Question

**Why do certain programs or systems rely on symlinks?**

Is there a history lesson here, similar to [Rob Pike's story about the origins of dotfiles](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205101508/https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp)?

I've read the wikipedia pages on [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) and [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), which thoroughly explain the *what*, but not the *why*

### Examples

On macOS the following directories are entirely symlinks

- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked`

Comment: who said that they rely on symlinks? You can copy the files instead of creating symlinks and they should still work, unless they expect some files in a symlinked directory to be the same

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming reliance since those directories are full with symlinks. Another way to ask this: Would systems break if you copied the files instead of using a symlink? Given the answer below my guess is that you would create silos that are less maintainable over time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many systems **rely** on *symlinks* essentially for **handling default settings**.

The relationship between a program name and the code that should run is not always biunivocal (a 1 to 1 relationship) :

**a 1 to many :** Because different implementations of whatever commonly used program can coexist on a system, and, users and historical scripts just do not need/want to care… and simply fire some common command name, administrators need to symlink :

Just think of the most basic `sh` command. Just many shells exist *bash, csh, ksh, zsh…* pffff… and just many of the associated binaries can coexist on the system. Which one of these should be launched when simply asked for `sh` ?

On my system the arbitrary decision is as simple as :

```
616457 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 14 mai     2021 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Of course we immediately think of `sh` but the same would happen with just many commonly used command names (*awk, bzip2, bc, cpio, gzip, lex, tar, yacc*…) On my system :

```
616450 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15  8 juil.   2020 /bin/awk -> ../usr/bin/gawk
484973 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10  8 juil.   2020 /usr/bin/yacc -> yacc.bison
484674 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 27 nov.   02:14 /usr/bin/lex -> flex
```

Of course, all this goes similarly when different versions of the same program coexist. Think principally of compilers, language interpreters, not to say running kernel's source code. On my system :

```
484470 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 26 nov.   23:43 /usr/bin/gcc -> /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/10.4.0/gcc
485883 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19  7 déc.  01:41 /usr/src/linux -> linux-5.4.225-0707a
```

---

**a many to 1 :** The other need to **rely** on symlinks is for very special filesystems such as `/sys` where the information resides in one unique pseudo-file which is handy to access through several paths when searching for it.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense, thank you. I never thought of symlinks as being their own abstraction layer for components of the operating system. Also, would you mind adding a little more to what you mean by biunivocal in this context? I'm not familiar with it's usage in computing... is this what you meant by "*different versions of the same program coexist*"

Comment: there's no reliance in the case of `sh`. You can `cp /bin/bash /bin/sh` and no one would complain. Or you can install a true sh into /bin/sh

Comment: @will-wright-eng : biunivocal ? I mean a 1 to 1 relationship. In my first example taken between a generic program name and the "real" binary is a 1 to many relationship. Hence the need for a default. In my last example (/sys like pseudo fs) its a many to 1 relation ship.

Comment: @phuclv : *"install a true sh"*… what do you mean ? THE Thompson shell ? Errr ? Who would want/risk that under anything else than a pre 1975 AT&T Unix ©™® ?

Comment: @MC68020 obviously bash and sh are completely different things. If you make sh a symlink to bash then bash will run in sh mode which isn't sh at all but a few features of bash will be enabled

Comment: sh is the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) described in the POSIX standard, and bash is the [Bourne again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne-again%20shell) shell

Comment: @phuclv [The Bourne shell and POSIX sh are actually slightly different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98912/70524) (and that's aside from POSIX sh being an abstract entity).